# How to sort the input of a batch file

Tags: sql, batch-file, sqlcmd

I'm using the following script to execute a bunch **.sql** statements.

```
@echo off
ECHO %USERNAME% started the batch process at %TIME%  >output.txt

for %%s in (*.sql)  do (
sqlcmd.exe  -S.\ -E -i "%%s" >>output.txt
    )
pause
```

However, I want to make sure the files are sorted (name) because I don't think I can guarantee that the list is in order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to worry, FOR sorts (process) the files by name, but if you want another way you can sort the output file too:

```
@echo off
ECHO %USERNAME% started the batch process at %TIME%  >output.txt

FOR %%s in ("*.sql")  do (sqlcmd.exe -S.\ -E -i "%%s" >> "%TEMP%\output.txt")

TYPE "%TEMP%\output.txt" | SORT > ".\Final_Output.txt"

Pause&Exit
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to loop over them in order of name

```
for /f %%s in ('dir *.sql /b /o:n') do (
sqlcmd.exe  -S.\ -E -i "%%s" >>output.txt
    )
pause
```